# Failed to find component class for 'supervised_embeddings'. Unknown component name

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-nlu

I'd like to test SpacyNLP pipeline combined with the supervised_embeddings. If I try to launch it, though, I'm getting this stack trace. This does not happen if, in the config.yml, I just keep supervised_embeddings only. 
If I try to leave the SpacyNLP pipeline only, though, I get this error:

```
InvalidConfigError: No pipeline specified and unknown pipeline template 'SpacyNLP' passed. Known pipeline templates: pretrained_embeddings_spacy, keyword, supervised_embeddings
```

Is there something that I am missing?

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa\nlu\registry.py in get_component_class(component_name)
    140             try:
--> 141                 return utils.class_from_module_path(component_name)
    142             except Exception:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa\nlu\utils\__init__.py in class_from_module_path(module_path)
    143     else:
--> 144         return globals()[module_path]
    145

KeyError: 'supervised_embeddings'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-971025f984ec> in <module>
      8
      9 # trainer to educate our pipeline
---> 10 trainer = Trainer(config.load("config.yml"))
     11
     12 # train the model!

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa\nlu\model.py in __init__(self, cfg, component_builder, skip_validation)
    146         # required packages are available
    147         if not self.skip_validation:
--> 148             components.validate_requirements(cfg.component_names)
    149
    150         # build pipeline

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa\nlu\components.py in validate_requirements(component_names)
     34     failed_imports = set()
     35     for component_name in component_names:
---> 36         component_class = registry.get_component_class(component_name)
     37         failed_imports.update(
     38             find_unavailable_packages(component_class.required_packages())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa\nlu\registry.py in get_component_class(component_name)
    148                     "listed as part of the `component_classes` in "
    149                     "`rasa.nlu.registry.py` or is a proper name of a class "
--> 150                     "in a module.".format(component_name)
    151                 )
    152         else:

Exception: Failed to find component class for 'supervised_embeddings'. Unknown component name. Check your configured pipeline and make sure the mentioned component is not misspelled. If you are creating your own component, make sure it is either listed as part of the `component_classes` in `rasa.nlu.registry.py` or is a proper name of a class in a module.
```

config.yml file

```
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/
language: it_core_news_sm
pipeline:
  - name: supervised_embeddings
  - name: SpacyNLP

# Configuration for Rasa Core.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/policies/
policies:
  - name: MemoizationPolicy
  - name: KerasPolicy
  - name: MappingPolicy
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the [preconfigured pipelines](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/choosing-a-pipeline/#pre-configured-pipelines) (these are predefined templates) with the actual [NLU components](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/).

If you are using a preconfigured, it would be:

```
pipeline: supervised_embeddings
```

which is the same (kind of shortcut) as

```
pipeline:
- name: "WhitespaceTokenizer"
- name: "RegexFeaturizer"
- name: "CRFEntityExtractor"
- name: "EntitySynonymMapper"
- name: "CountVectorsFeaturizer"
- name: "EmbeddingIntentClassifier"
```